# Make List Starts with zero

Tags: lists

How can I make such a list? My code is off.

```
3.0 Main
  3.1 Sub
  3.2 Sub
   3.2.1 SubSub
   3.2.2 SubSub

 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{enumitem}

  \begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Main
    \begin{enumerate}
     \item Sub
     \begin{enumerate}
        \item SubSub
        \item SubSub
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably look into the [`enumitem` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf). The package provides the option `start` with which you can specify the first number of an `enumerate` list, such as `\begin{enumerate}[start=0]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `label`, `ref`, and `start` in a combination to make this work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*.0,ref=\arabic*,start=3]
  \item Main
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi.\arabic*]
      \item Sub
        \begin{enumerate}[label*=.\arabic*]
          \item SubSub
          \item SubSub
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can this be done with sections (Main) subsection. and subsubsection?

Comment: @OOzyPal ? Do you mean with the `\section` and `\subsection` commands? I'd not advice it, but sure: `\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}` and your numbering for headings should look like this.